# how to change column name and change a value in a table via a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the table below :

```
Desk_name | head
ali       | john 
cars ln   | max
pol fr    | max
jus       | john
```

I want to create a stored procedure in order to have in return :

```
Name      | sector_head
ali mm    | john
cars ln   | max
pol fr    | max
jus mm    | john
```

As you can see the column name  has changed (from 'Name' to 'Desk_name') and every name in the 'Name' column has the abbreviation "mm" at the end of each values if it is a single word (ali and jus).

How can I do such a stored procedure (i am using sql server)?

Thanks

Comment: 'ali' is a single word not like 'cars ln'. If I have a single word I want to add 'mm' in front of it, so 'ali' become 'ali mm'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to supply `ALIAS` on it, example

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(Desk_name)) LIKE '% %'  -- finds any space in string
            THEN Desk_name 
            ELSE Desk_name + ' mm'
       END AS Name, 
       head AS sector_head 
FROM   tableName
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3f47/1)

Comment: @JoeGJoseph yeah, I experienced that also, While you are still typing the answer and someone submits which is your answer is the same answer as his, he usually then accused you of copying the answer which is rude. :D

Answer (score 4):

try this:

In sql server

```
select case when charindex(' ',ltrim(rtrim(Desk_name)))=0 
            then Desk_name+' mm' 
            else Desk_name 
       end  as Name ,
       head as sector_head
from your_table
```

## [SQL fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ead5e/1)

Comment: Now is ok, add [this fiddle code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ead5e/1) for sample if you want

Comment: nice! `+1` for using `charindex`

Comment: @Yaroslav: Thank you so much.. I have added it in my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Desk_name = 'ali' OR Desk_name = 'jus'  THEN Desk_name + ' mm' ELSE Desk_name END AS Name, 
head AS sector_head
FROM DeskName
```

Comment: this is not dynamic, what if it has a value of `hello world`?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you need to rename column Desk_name before updating table. To do this you may try this:

```
sp_RENAME 'YourTableName.Desk_name' , 'Name', 'COLUMN'
```

It should rename your column. After that you should use Joe's or John's solution to update records in table.